# URL Encoding Issue %3D instead of (=)

Tags: url, encoding

I have a url that's displayed from a variable in a search form, but due to the url encoding, its putting the "%3d" instead of the "=" sign, which obviously doesn't work.

I know you can't "turn off" url encoding can you? Don't you have to set it up to allow special characters?

Here is the code: Again, I need the = signs below to show in the resulting url, not %3d

```
<?php _e('Job Type'); ?><br />
    <select name="custom_field_id[]=10" class="do_input2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="custom_field_value_10=Full-time">Full-time</option>
    <option value="custom_field_value_10=Part-time">Part-time</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean that you want the submitted form data to look like this:

```
custom_field_id[]=10=custom_field_value_10=Full-time
```

In either the URL query string, or in the POST body of an `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` request?  If so, then no, you cannot do that.  That is a violation of both the URL and `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` specifications.  `=` is a reserved separator character that cannot appear unencoded in the `name` and `value` fields, it must be url-encoded as `%3D`:

```
custom_field_id%5B%5D%3D10=custom_field_value_10%3DFull-time
```

It is the receiver's responsibility to url-decode the submitted data before then processing it.  As such, it would see `custom_field_id[]=10` and `custom_field_value_10=Full-time` values, just as they appeared in the original HTML.

Comment: Here's the thing...

I'm using a theme which in the admin panel you can assign certain search fields to categories, but in order for the assigned search options to appear on the search page, it has to be set for "all categories" which doesn't make sense on another part of the site where people fill out the initial form... for say a Real Estate post... I obviously don't need "job type" to show there. So, I only assigned it to job categories - this it only shows on the post page for jobs. However, as stated, if it isn't assigned to all categories, the option box won't display on the search page.

Comment: If you do do it like this, then the resulting url displays properly - custom_field_id[]=10=custom_field_value_10=Full-time

Again though, I can't have it setup like that...

So basically, I'm just creating my own search form, which I've already done successfully for all the other categories, but for some reason this category has the (equal) signs assigned to it. Thus the problem. If I can just change the %3D to stay as the equal sign, then I'm golden.

Comment: I also see that an (=) sign is a Reserved character and can be used as long as it's for that specific defined purpose. I dunno... I'll keep tinkering.

Comment: Such a URL may be **displayed** to the user in its unencoded format, but that is merely browser behavior for display purposes only. Most people not familiar with how HTTP works do not understand URL encoding. But such a URL has to be **transmitted** to the server in the encoded format I showed, and the browser handles that for you.